# К каждому тегу li добавлять в два раза больше значения свойства

Tags: javascript, jquery

Встала такая интересная задача:
есть html

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">пункт 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">пункт 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">пункт 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">пункт 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">пункт 5</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Делаю всплытие пунктов меню как
[здесь](https://tympanus.net/Development/OffCanvasMenuEffects/sideslide.html) (нажать на бургер).

Дело в том, что пункты меню будут добавляться и тогда уже `li:nth-child(2,3.4....){transform:translate3d(0,500px,0);}` не прокатит.

Поэтому хочу к каждому следующему li добавлять translate3d на 500px больше чем у предыдущего li

пример:

```
1 li transform:translate3d(0,500px,0);
2 li transform:translate3d(0,1000px,0);
3 li transform:translate3d(0,1500px,0);
4 li transform:translate3d(0,2000px,0);
.....
```

Comment: Пункты меню будут добавляться динамически?

Comment: @МайклМиллер есть подозрение, что эта задача решается в три строки.

Comment: @NickolayRudak нет, ручками в html

Comment: Ответ ниже решает вашу проблему средствами js, с помощью css в текущей структуре html вы не сможете ничего сделать

Comment: конечно за исключением добавления в css li:nth-child(для каждого пункта меню)

Comment: @NickolayRudak CSS не так примитивен, как кажется, a JS - это уже тяжёлая артиллерия))

Comment: @МайклМиллер извините, что мой ответ не попадает под метки)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var a = 500;
$('ul li').each(function(){
 $(this).css("transform","translate3d(0,"+a+"px,0)");
 a+=500;
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, просто не знал как это написать на js, спасибо!

Comment: В моём "хроме" выдаёт ошибку:     <br>

Error: {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 14,
  "colno": 1
}